# How much performance do I lose, when running the desktop (but not using it)?

Tags: performance, headless

Using `raspi-config` you can decide whether the pi should boot into a desktop environment or not. I only use my pi over `ssh` so if the desktop is there or not does not matter to me at all.

My question would be: Do I take a noticeable performance hit, with the desktop enabled, when I'm not using any extra graphical applications?

Comment: To my experience the cpu load of an X server running with nothing to use it is negligible to CPU load. But then again why start it if it is never going to be used?

Answer (score 2):

If no one is actually using the desktop, you're not going to notice a direct performance hit, since it is not contending for the CPU -- it's idle.

However, it will occupy a chunk of memory.  This may or may not be significant depending on what else is going on.  To have a look at how much RAM you are actually using, check `free`; the important number is the second one on the second line (`-/+ buffers/cache` -> `free`).  If that's at least half of the `total` on the first line, don't worry.

If you are using most of your available RAM, performance will suffer because the system uses whatever is left over for [page/file caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache); this is why output from `free` can be a bit confusing (if you don't take caching into account, it may appear that you are always using almost all of what's available).  The page cache is a good thing, which is why leaving 100 MB or so for it on the pi is beneficial.

Personally, I don't care about graphical boots or logins; if I want to use the GUI, I just log in on a console and use `startx`.  If you generally aren't using the desktop, you might as well disable the display manager service.  On raspbian wheezy, presuming you haven't changed the default runlevel (2):

```
sudo update-rc.d lightdm disable S 2
```

Or you could just use `S 2 3 4 5` to be sure.

If you are interested in which processes occupy the most memory, install and run `top`, hit shift-F, go down arrow one to select `%MEM`, hit s then ESC and the stuff at the top of the list is it; `RES` is the important number.  `X`, the foundation of the GUI stack, may use 75-100 MB all by itself.

Comment: Didn't know about the display manager service. Thanks for the heads up.